# Difference between pprev and pskip pointers in the CBlockIndex class?

Tags: bitcoin-core, block, bitcoin-core-development

In the Bitcoin Core [there](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chain.h#L151) is class called `CBlockIndex` which as its name appears is the implementation of blocks. This class has two variable that for me they looks the same:

```
class CBlockIndex
{
public:

    //! pointer to the index of the predecessor of this block
    CBlockIndex* pprev{nullptr};

    //! pointer to the index of some further predecessor of this block
    CBlockIndex* pskip{nullptr};
```

The first one (`pprev`) is more straightforward and I understand it. It is simply a pointer to the previous `CBlockIndex` object in the chain. But the second one is not clear for me. What does the comment means by `pointer to the index of some further predecossor`? What it actually is and what are its use cases?